# Show recenly updated only one post per category

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display only one post (most recently updated) from each category. Here is my code, it display all posts, how can I show only one post per category, please help.

```
$paged = wp_get_paged();
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'paged'         =>  $paged
)); 
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query  ->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'inc/content', 'post' );
endwhile;
else:
    get_template_part( 'inc/content', 'none' );
endif;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Get all Category details](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)
2. [Make new Query for `category ID`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters)
3. [Only 1 post each category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters)
4. [Orderby last `modified`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

```php
<?php
$cats   = get_categories();
$query  = new WP_Query;

foreach ( $cats as $cat ) :
    $query->query( array(
        'cat'                 => $cat->term_id,
        'posts_per_page'      => 1,
        'orderby'             => 'modified'
    ));

    ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
 
       <?php the_title(); ?>
       <!-- do whatever you else you want that you can do in a normal loop -->

    <?php endwhile ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

---

### Update

The smartest way I can think of is as follows. (Of course, it filters the **data**, not the `query`) **Therefore, paging does not work properly.** In this case, we can ask the data to be transformed into a `new Query` and paginate again, but I guess this would not be a logical solution.

I could not come up with any more solutions. I think of creating an `SQL query` accordingly, which I am not very good at with SQL queries. I hope an appropriate answer will come.

**Note**: [This maybe answers your question.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/912/162608)

```php
<?php
$cats = array();
    ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
      $cats_in_post = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );
    
      $diff = array_diff($cats_in_post, $cats);

      if( count($diff) == 0 ) continue;

      $cats = array_unique( array_merge($cats, $cats_in_post) );
     ?>
 
       <?php the_title(); ?>
       <!-- do whatever you else you want that you can do in a normal loop -->

    <?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: thanks.. however I had 14000 categories and 200K posts, this query was trying to load all posts from all categories, I just wanted PAGED so I added but it was still trying to load all posts which never loaded as over 200K posts are there...

Comment: In this case, this code will list you 14k posts. One from each category.

Comment: I didn't expect there would be so many categories and articles. Also, now I understand what you want to do. You want at most one post per category in any archive list. I took this situation as an independent loop containing one post from each category. Let's see what we can do. Let me think a little bit.

Comment: Exactly, I have 36 posts per page.. and I want them to be from different categories and also should work with current pagination... I found one article where he was also caching queries but I couldn't follow it, because he was working with custom taxonomy.. thanks

Comment: @Themer Maybe you can find the answer to this question by asking on "wordpress.stackexchange.com". There are many experts out there who are experts in Tom J Nowell ♦ and WordPress. You can try your luck there. Still, I updated my answer. But it probably won't be a complete answer.

Comment: I did it another way, I added a global variable array for category IDs that has already been displayed, $excluded_categories,, then I added CAT ID from template in it.. so I now I have listm then I checked !in_array() display template and removed the Query from loop and added pre_get_posts hook.. then on homepage, I added an IF with a number of see how many posts I wanted to display... it does the job, but sometimes on some pages it skips 1-2 posts, which I dont mind :) thanks